# How to install apxs module on apache 2.4.6

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I have just used `apt-get update` and my apache has been updated to `2.4.6`.

i want to install apxs for compiling modules and i get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a third party repository, or a beta version of Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 13.10 (currently in beta) looks to be the first version with Apache 2.4 (and it is indeed 2.4.6).. but the version of `apache2-prefork-dev` that it's trying to install is from Ubuntu 12.04 (as that's the release which has the `-common` package at version `2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4`).

So, the answer is to fix the situation that's causing the conflict, by making sure that the versions of the various Apache related packages are all being fetched from the same generation of Ubuntu.. but to tell you specifically how to do that, you'll need to provide more information about how this system's been configured and what you did to get it into this state.

Comment: Actually i was trying to upgrade to php 5.5, i have ubuntu 12.04 . then i ran following commands `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then i get that error. I have now reverted back to old snapshot but want to know whats better way to approach

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 13.10 you need to install apache2-dev instead of apache2-prefork-dev to get apxs.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Install the software neccesary for APXS by typuing the following commands,

```
"sudo apt-get install httpd-devel"
```

Type

```
"echo "extension=apc.so" > /etc/php.d/apc.ini"
```

and press "Enter" to enable APXS's configuration for your server.

restart Apache (If needed.)

Comment: This looks like a mess. That httpd-devel package doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: If you are on ubuntu, it's apache2-dev

Comment: Nope apache2-dev does not work as well: `➜  ~ sudo apt-get -y install apache2-dev     ...
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-dev : Depends: libapr1-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`